# How to use VersionEye maven plugin to scan java dependencies without connecting to external site?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-plugin, nexus

I have to use some maven plugin to scan dependency in my project and generate report.

Can i use this plugin without the API Key ?
Can i use it without internet and without connection to external site?As i have local repository for jars?
Is there any similar tools/maven plugin?

https://github.com/versioneye/versioneye_maven_plugin

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.versioneye</groupId>
      <artifactId>versioneye-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <apiKey>MY_SECRET_API_KEY</apiKey>
        <organisation>YOUR_ORGANISATION</organisation>
        <team>Owners</team>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I'm going with: no. No. No. And no.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is how to break 7 work around this proprietary softwares copy protection, this is obviously not legal and therefore cannot be answered here.

To use this software you have to acquire an API Key as described  here: https://github.com/versioneye/versioneye_maven_plugin#api-key

So the answer is NO!